# Autocompletar por iniciales - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Hace algún tiempo buscaba un método para autocompletar, lo he encontrado, ahora lo que busco es que ese `autocomplete` solo funcione con las iniciales de la lista.

Por ejemplo: al pulsar `M` aparezcan todas las ciudades que **inician con `M`**, no aquellas que contienen la `M` en medio de la palabra.

Aquí el código, aunque es un poco largo.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the site header
 *
 * @package Customizr
 * @since Customizr 3.5.0
 */
?>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Xalapa, Ver. Mx",
      "Boca del Rio, Ver. Mx",
      "Aguascalientes, Aguascalientes, México"
    ];
    $( "#ciudades" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
          change: function(e, ui) 
          {
            if (!ui.item) 
              {
                $(this).val("");
              }
          },
        response: function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length == 0) 
            {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }
        }).on("keydown", function(e) 
          {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) 
            {
              $(this).val("");
            }
          })
  } );
  </script>

  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<!-- formulario personalizado de usuarios -->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
  <div class="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">

  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group two-fields">
        <label for="">Registro Express</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo(isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null); ?>" placeholder="Email" required aria-required="true" />
          <input type="text" id="ciudades" font-color="red" class="" name="ciudades" placeholder="Ciudad">
          <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
</form>

<?php do_action( '__after_header' ) ?>
```

No soy experto en `Javascript`, en `MySQL` usamos el `like` para buscar por iniciales así `variableBusqueda%` o `%variable%` para buscar en toda la cadena, pero aquí no le encuentro.

Espero puedan guiarme. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución es usar una funcion como parámetro de [`source`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

> La tercera variación, ***una devolución de llamada***, proporciona la mayor flexibilidad y se puede utilizar para conectar cualquier fuente de datos a `Autocomplete`, incluido `JSONP`. La función obtiene dos argumentos:
>
> - Un objeto `request`, con una única propiedad `term`, que se refiere al valor actualmente en la entrada de texto.
>
>   Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa "nuevo yo" en un campo de ciudad, el término `Autocomplete` será igual a "nuevo yo".
> - Un función `response`, que espera un único argumento: los datos para sugerir al usuario.
>
>   Estos datos deben filtrarse según el término proporcionado y pueden estar en cualquiera de los formatos descritos anteriormente para datos locales simples. [...] Siempre debe llamar a la función `response`, incluso si encuentra un error. Esto asegura que el `widget` siempre tenga el estado correcto.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "Xalapa, Ver. Mx",
    "Boca del Rio, Ver. Mx",
    "Aguascalientes, Aguascalientes, México"
  ];
  $("#ciudades").autocomplete({
      // AQUI pasamos la función
      source: (request, response) => {
        // Filtramos el arreglo de tags
        let result = availableTags.filter(tag => {
          // Implementamos nuestro filtro personalizado
          return tag.toLowerCase().startsWith(request.term.toLowerCase();
        });
        // Llamamos a `response` con los datos filtrados
        response(result);
      },
      change: function(e, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
          $(this).val("");
        }
      },
      response: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length == 0) {
          $(this).val("");
        }
      }
    })
    .on("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(this).val("");
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="ciudades" font-color="red" class="" name="ciudades" placeholder="Ciudad">
```

Comment: Genial amigo!!!!!, problema solucionado!!, Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Marcos

Comment: ups, amigo Marcos, todo funciona como lo deseo, solo que al buscar una ciudad con mayuscula, no la lista, solo si es minúsucula

Comment: Perfecto!!! funciona!

Comment: he buscado ejemplos aqui para reemplazar los tags con un archivo JSON pero no logro encontrarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con una expresion regular asi :

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Xalapa, Ver. Mx",
      "Boca del Rio, Ver. Mx",
      "Aguascalientes, Aguascalientes, México"
    ];
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( availableTags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      },
          change: function(e, ui)                     
          {        
            if (!ui.item) 
              {
                $(this).val("");
              }
          },
        response: function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length == 0) 
            {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }
        }).on("keydown", function(e) 
          {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) 
            {
              $(this).val("");
            }
          })
  } );
```

De esta manera te da el resultado sin importar si pones una mayúscula o minúscula, el parámetro "i" es el que logra esto, si deseases que funcione solo si empieza con mayúscula o minúscula solo quitalo de la función

Comment: ah mira el código de marcos, solucionó el problema, pero me encontré con que en el celular siempre al escribir lo hace con mayusculas y este código no tiene ese problema. Muchas Gracias Stre_leon